# Ambiguous layout warnings for UILabels in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, uilabel

I have two `UILabel` views next to each other in an `UITableViewCell`. The left one has one line, the right one can have multiple lines and uses whatever horizontal space that is left. Both labels have the same distance from the top of the cell. The height of the cell is dictated by the height of the right label. In some cases, I see unwanted additional space above and under the right `UILabel`, and therefore they are not top-aligned. Looking into it more, I found that `hasAmbiguousLayout` returns `YES` for both labels.

When I call `constraintsAffectingLayoutForAxis` in the debugger, I get the following output:

```
(lldb) po [0x7b769520 constraintsAffectingLayoutForAxis:0]
<__NSArrayM 0x7b6cb340>(
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7b76abf0 h=--& v=--& 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Left' H:|-(0)-[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7b768fc0]   (Names: '|':MyTVCell:0x7b769330'MyTVCell' )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b76b010 H:|-(15)-[UILabel:0x7b769520'Number']   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7b768fc0 )>,
<NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint:0x7b769a90 H:[UILabel:0x7b769520'Number'(131)] Hug:250 CompressionResistance:750>
)
```

For a second `UILabel` that is positioned to the right of the first `UILabel`, I get this:

```
(lldb) po [0x7b769710 constraintsAffectingLayoutForAxis:0]
<__NSArrayM 0x7b6cb9e0>(
<NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint:0x7b769a90 H:[UILabel:0x7b769520'Number'(131)] Hug:250 CompressionResistance:750>,
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7b76abf0 h=--& v=--& 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Left' H:|-(0)-[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7b768fc0]   (Names: '|':MyTVCell:0x7b769330'MyTVCell' )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b76b010 H:|-(15)-[UILabel:0x7b769520'Number']   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7b768fc0 )>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b76b230 H:[UILabel:0x7b769520'Number']-(15)-[UILabel:0x7b769710'Q12472']>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b76ab90 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7b768fc0(320)]>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b76b310 UILabel:0x7b769710'Q12472'.trailing == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7b768fc0.trailing - 15>
)
```

Could anyone explain based on the output above why these labels have an ambiguous layout?

**Update:** The `NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint` constraint belongs to the `contentView` of the cell. Both labels have set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `NO`.

**Update 2:** Here are the constraints I have for the contentView and the two labels:

```
2015-02-26 07:35:25.559 contentView constraints: (
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7be541e0 V:|-(8)-[UILabel:0x7be537d0]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7be535a0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7be54240 H:|-(15)-[UILabel:0x7be537d0]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7be535a0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7be54310 V:|-(8)-[UILabel:0x7be53990]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7be535a0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7be54340 H:[UILabel:0x7be537d0]-(15)-[UILabel:0x7be53990]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7be54370 UILabel:0x7be53990.trailing == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7be535a0.trailing - 15>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7be543c0 UILabel:0x7be53990.bottom == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7be535a0.bottom - 8>",
    "<NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint:0x7be53cd0 H:[UILabel:0x7be537d0(109)] Hug:250 CompressionResistance:750>",
    "<NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint:0x7be53d10 V:[UILabel:0x7be537d0(21)] Hug:250 CompressionResistance:750>",
    "<NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint:0x7be53eb0 H:[UILabel:0x7be53990(20)] Hug:250 CompressionResistance:750>",
    "<NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint:0x7be53f10 V:[UILabel:0x7be53990(20)] Hug:250 CompressionResistance:750>"
)
2015-02-26 07:35:25.560 left label constraints: (
    "<NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint:0x7be53cd0 H:[UILabel:0x7be537d0(109)] Hug:250 CompressionResistance:750>",
    "<NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint:0x7be53d10 V:[UILabel:0x7be537d0(21)] Hug:250 CompressionResistance:750>"
)
2015-02-26 07:35:25.561 right label constraints:(
    "<NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint:0x7be53eb0 H:[UILabel:0x7be53990(20)] Hug:250 CompressionResistance:750>",
    "<NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint:0x7be53f10 V:[UILabel:0x7be53990(20)] Hug:250 CompressionResistance:750>"
)
```

Here is a picture showing the constraints I have and what goes wrong:

[image]

Comment: Are you doing the layout in a xib/storyboard or in code?

Comment: In code, using PureLayout

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I solved it by adding for the right `UILabel`:

```
[self.bodyLabel setContentHuggingPriority: UILayoutPriorityFittingSizeLevel forAxis: UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
```

The other thing is that I was testing for ambiguity in `updateConstraints`, while I should have done it at the end of `layoutSubviews`

Answer (score 2):

Ah! Have you turned off the 
`translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` property for every subview in the view hierarchy of the cell.contentView?

The output shows evidence of clashes between your auto layout and the default autoresizing behaviour. In xibs this can be turned off for everything with a checkbox, but in code you have to do it on a per view level.

Comment: Not according to the output you've given, it explicitly lists autoresizing constraint entries. ```<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7b76abf0 h=--& v=--& 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Left' H:|-(0)-[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7b768fc0]   (Names: '|':MyTVCell:0x7b769330'MyTVCell' )>```

Comment: Interesting. At the same point where I check for `constraintsAffectingLayoutForAxis`, `self.bodyLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` returns `NO`

Comment: Read the update, thats cool. In the initial question you say that the height of the cell (therefore the contentView) is defined by the height of the right label? That'd usually achieved by adding a constraint to the contentView to  equal to the height of the right label or at least a minimal height. Since you're applying (either directly through auto layout or indirectly through PureLayout) a constraint to the contentView and the autoresize messages are related to the contentView might the conflict not be there?

Comment: I have added all the constraints for the contentView and two labels in another update. I think it covers the top and bottom constraint between the right label and the contentView.

Comment: I am using UIWebView in UICollectionViewCell. I have set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false for every subview, still getting the same error. position and height are ambiguous for UIWebView.