# iOS Autolayout 2 multi-line UILabels inside UITableViewCell having extra padding

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout, uilabel

I am planning to use two UILabels of equal width side by side in UITableViewCell. Though, the content inside the each label would be dynamic in length and hence UILable's height would be different even though contained inside same table cell.I have used Auto-Layout under XCode 6.0. I am able to achieve everything through auto-layout constraints but only hurdle is the additional padding existing on UILable as shown in reference  Image. I just want the labels to be occupying exact fitting size and not with the additional padding as seen in refernce Image [image]

Here are constraints applied:

[image]

Comment: What additional padding do you require? I don't understand what problem you are having or where the error is.

Comment: Well, My issue is the additional space/padding seen on the labels for example..On 1st cell -- Right Side Label, On 2nd cell -- Left Side Lable.  I just want the labels to be having exact size that fits them so that the content of each label inside the same cell exists on the same horizontal line and not like the shown in reference image above.

Comment: Please provide all the constraints you are applying on individual labels in the cell. Then only someone will be able to answer the question.

Comment: Let me guess: There is an equal-height constraint between those two labels ...

Comment: @Thomas: Nop. There is an equal width constraint between two labels

Comment: Yes but it seems like at least one constraint is responsible for resizing the "smaller" label to the height of the bigger one. Is there an equal-height constraint between the label and the superview?

Comment: @Gandalf: I have added the constraints details as an Image to Original question. Hope that may surely be helpful

Comment: Make your bottom constraints greaterThanOrEqual (not just equal) to the desired margin. That will allow the shorter label to bring its bottom boundary up, reducing the vertical padding.

Comment: @mbm29414: Hey ! Thats fantastic tip !! Its done now !! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @iThirst Sure! Auto layout can be a bit tricky, but if you think through exactly what you need to do, you can usually find a pretty simple way to get it done.

Comment: I had a similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28696264/ambiguous-layout-warnings-for-uilabels-in-uitableviewcell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you have it. Your labels have constraints to the top and bottom of the superview. So when the superview changes its heights, the labels increase their height too to match the constraints.

Answer (score 1):

There are two vertical constraints on each label. Now considering the scenario that you need your label to be top-aligned, you can keep the top constraint as it is. Change the `bottom constraint` to flexible values i.e. `>=8`. If you want it to be bottom aligned then you need to loosen the `top constraint`.