# Different Height for same UILabel Text

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have two UILabel with (orange and pink one) one is multiline label and other one is just one label. Two of this component (which has same texts) is  inside UIStackView and this Stackview is inside UITableView (Automatic dimension). My problem is that whether I set the same text to UILabels their heights look different. I'm searching for this problem for two days but none of solutions work for me.

[Ambiguous layout warnings for UILabels in UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28696264/ambiguous-layout-warnings-for-uilabels-in-uitableviewcell)

**Label1** has top, left, right layout and **Label2** has top,left,right,bottom.
**UIStackView** distribution is `.fillProportionally`

I want the labels has same height If they are same for example;

For View1;

- Label1 = "Multiline Label 1 Text which is two line"
- Label2 = "One Line Label 2 text"

  For View2;
- Label1 = "Multiline Label 1 Text which is two line"
- Label2 = "One Line Label 2 text"

**What I want is:** view1 and view2 height should be same because they have same elements with same content In them. Stackview which has this view1 and view2 has fill proportionally option should set Its height according to view1 + view2 height.

[image: example]
[image: screen example]

Container view which gets a xib file (It is just a xib file which has two label in it with the constraints I mention earlier).

```
class ViewWithLabel: UIView {

@IBOutlet weak var firstLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var secondLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var containerView: UIView!

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    
    self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    // first: load the view hierarchy to get proper outlets
    let name = String(describing: type(of: self))
    let nib = UINib(nibName: name, bundle: .main)
    nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)
    
    addSubview(containerView)
    containerView.frame = self.bounds
    containerView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth,.flexibleHeight]
    
}

convenience init(firstLabelText: String, secondLabelText: String) {
    self.init()
    firstLabel.text = firstLabelText
    secondLabel.text = secondLabelText
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    firstLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.frame.width
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}
```

Another container view which has a Stackview and gets the above view and add to Stackview.

```
    class ViewWithStack: UIView {

    let verticalStackView: UIStackView = {
           let s = UIStackView()
           s.distribution = .fillEqually
           s.spacing = 0
           s.axis = .vertical
           s.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
           return s
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 6.0
        self.layer.applySketchShadow(color: UIColor(red:0.56, green:0.56, blue:0.56, alpha:1), alpha: 0.2, x: 0, y: 0, blur: 10, spread: 0)
        
        addSubview(verticalStackView)
        verticalStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
        let bottomEqual = verticalStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: 0)
        bottomEqual.isActive = true
        verticalStackView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor,constant: 0).isActive = true
        verticalStackView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor,constant: 0).isActive = true
        verticalStackView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 20, bottom: 10, right: 20)
        verticalStackView.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
    }

    convenience init(orientation: NSLayoutConstraint.Axis,labelsArray: [UIView]) {
        self.init()
        verticalStackView.axis = orientation
        for label in labelsArray {
            verticalStackView.addArrangedSubview(label)
        }
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    }
```

**EDIT:** If I write `firstLabel.sizeToFit()` in `layoutSubviews` function. First label looks fixed but content view still has same height and there is a big gap between label 1 and label 2.

**EDIT 2:** When I add `setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .vertical)` for labels. First label looks okay but second label looks bigger too.

Comment: Try different fill modes for stackview, for example `fill proportionally`

Comment: How do you want them to be?

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini I added more detail.

Comment: @henrik-dmg It is already fill proportionally.

Comment: So how the remaining space should fill ?

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini Actually there shouldn't be any space. I mean Stackview which has view1 + view2 element should has height of view1 + view2

Comment: You probably have some issues with the container `UIView` and it's constraints. It prevents self sizing.

Comment: I added my containerView.

Comment: @EmreÖnder - a little confusing... Do you want Yellow and Pink frames to *always* be the same size as each other? So, if the top pair has a lot of text, so it wraps to multiple lines, do you want the lower pair to be as big (with extra space)? Or, the other way around - yellow frames should fit the amount of text?

Comment: Other way around. I want all text boxes should fit the amount of the text, not more.

Comment: @EmreÖnder - tough to say what you might have setup wrong without seeing all of your layout constraints... I'm pretty sure you ***don't*** want to use `.fillProportionally` though - that is probably the most misunderstood stack view option. If you have a [mcve] and can put it up on GitHub (or a file-share service), I expect I can fix your issue in just a couple minutes.